# Download an image from internet an convert it to byte[] in WinRT

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime

I'm trying to download an image from the internet, through the URL, to my Windows8-app and convert it to a byte[]. (BitmapImage isn't serializable)

Unfortunatly when I try to process this code, it crashes on the bytearray initialization since the Stream isn't seekable.

Is there ANY way to accomplish this? I've red that there isn't a stream yet that is seekable in WinRT...

```
private async Task<byte[]> DownloadImageFromWebsite(string url)
        {
            //BitmapImage result = null;
            byte[] result = null;

            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

                WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

                Stream imageStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                result = new byte[imageStream.Length];
                await imageStream.ReadAsync(result, 0, (int)imageStream.Length);


                response.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Instead of trying to read all the data in at once, you could read it in fixed-size chunks and concatenate those using a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) which is expandable. (That said, I don't really understand how this would interact with the async feature.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
result = new byte[imageStream.Length];
```

For an HTTP response stream, you don't know how big it will be until it's read.

*If* the server sends a `Content-Length` header, then you should be able to read it and size your array using it. However, you'll still have to fall back to reading the entire stream (of unknown size) into memory, as such:

```
private async Task<byte[]> DownloadImageFromWebsiteAsync(string url)
{
  try
  {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
    using (var result = new MemoryStream())
    {
      await imageStream.CopyToAsync(result);
      return result.ToArray();
    }
  }
  catch (WebException ex)
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

P.S. I recommend you use [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `HttpWebRequest`.